# Numpy: How to stack arrays in columns?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say that I have n numpy arrays of the same length. I would like to now create a numpy matrix, sucht that each column of the matrix is one of the numpy arrays. How can I achieve this? Now I'm doing this in a loop and it produces the wrong results.

Note: I have to be able to stack them next to each other one by one iteratively.

my code looks like assume that get_array is a function that returns a certain array based on its argument. I don't know until after the loop, how many columns that I'm going to have.

```
matrix = np.empty((n_rows,))
for item in sorted_arrays:
    array = get_array(item)
    matrix = np.vstack((matrix,array))
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try matrix.append(item)?

Comment: But I want them in the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time and again, we recommend collecting the arrays in a list, and making the final array with one call.  That's more efficient, and usually easier to get right.

```
alist = []
for item in sorted_arrays:
    alist.append(get_array(item)
```

or

```
alist = [get_array(item) for item in sorted_arrays]
```

There are various ways of assembling the list.  Since you want columns, and assuming `get_array` produces equal sized 1d arrays:

```
arr = np.column_stack(alist)
```

Collecting them in rows and transposing that works too:

```
arr = np.array(alist).T
arr = np.vstack(alist).T
arr = np.stack(alist).T
arr = np.stack(alist, axis=1)
```

If the arrays are already 2d

```
arr = np.concatenate(alist, axis=1)
```

All the `stack` variations use `concatenate`, just varying in how they tweak the shape(s) of the input arrays.  The key to using `concatenate` is to understand the dimensions and shapes, and how to add dimensions as needed.  That should, soon or later, become fluent in that kind of coding.

If they vary in shape or dimensions, things get messier.

Equally good is to put the arrays in a pre-allocated array.  But  you need to know the desired final shape

```
arr = np.zeros((m,n), dtype)
for i, item in enumerate(sorted_arrays):
    arr[:,i] = get_array(item)
```

`n` is `len(sorted_arrays)`, and `m` is the length of one of `get_array(item)`.  You also need to know the expected `dtype` (int, float etc).

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting all your arrays (or lists) into a matrix and then transposing it. This will work if all arrays are the same length.

```
mymatrix = np.asmatrix((array1, array2, array3)) #... putting arrays into matrix.
mymatrix = mymatrix.transpose()
```

This should output a matrix with each array as a column. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a, b, c, d np array of same length, the following code will accomplish what you want:

```
out_matrix = np.vstack([a, b, c, d]).transpose()
```

An example:

```
In [3]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [4]: b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])

In [5]: c = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5])

In [6]: d = np.array([6, 8, 2, 4])

In [10]: np.vstack([a, b, c, d]).transpose()
Out[10]: 
        array([[1, 5, 2, 6],
               [2, 6, 3, 8],
               [3, 7, 4, 2],
               [4, 8, 5, 4]])
```